# Form action change based on option select works only when in home

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, search

I am creating a custom search form for a WordPress project I am working on. The searchform.php code looks like this:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform col-md-4" >
    <input type="search" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="term" id="s" class="form-control" placeholder="Find Freelancers & Agencies">
    <select id="search-options">
        <option>Select...</option>
        <option value="Projects">Projects</option>
        <option value="Freelancers">Freelancers</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Basically I want to change the action of the form based on what the user is selecting as an option. I am using the following script for that:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery("#search-options").change(function(){
 // change fn on dept id
 var selected_opt = $(this).children(":selected").text(); // Get the selected option value

 switch(selected_opt){
 case "Projects":
    jQuery("#searchform").attr('action', '/advanced-search/');
 break;

 case "Freelancers":
    jQuery("#searchform").attr('action', '/service-provider-search/');
 break;

 default:
    jQuery("#searchform").attr('action', '#');
 // Default action
 }
});
});
```

The script is properly enqueued on my functions.php file.

I noticed though that while this works fine when I am on the home page, it's not working when I am on other pages. When I use the search form on other pages, the result URL is http://example.com/page/?term=search_term

Any suggestions?

Comment: Verify if `<form>` is present in those pages and if the script is being loaded in those pages too. Just add a `console.log('Form script loaded.');` inside `jQuery(document).ready` and see if it appears in the browser's DevTools console (F12 in Chrome).

Comment: Hi @AugustoMoura. Thank you for your reply. Yes I can confirm that both the form and the script are loaded on other pages too.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, it was a typo in line 3. All "$" signs should be "jQuery" when using jQuery to develop in WordPress due to a known compatibility mode restriction.

This line:

```
 var selected_opt = $(this).children(":selected").text(); // Get the selected option value
```

Should be like this instead:

```
 var selected_opt = jQuery(this).children(":selected").text(); // Get the selected option value
```